# Complejidad cognitiva en clase Factory

Tags: java, patrones-de-diseño, buenas-prácticas, eficiencia

tengo una duda con respecto a cómo hacer correctamente la creación de una clase factory sin aumentar la complejidad cognitiva.
La clase consta de un método estático que devuelve una implementación en función de un nombre. 
Al ser una aplicación grande, hay muchas implementaciones por lo que validar cuál ha de usarse requiere de muchos condicionales. Y por lo tanto, la complegidad cognitiva suma uno por cada `if`.
La clase sería algo parecido a esto:

```
    public class ImplementadorFactory {

        private ImplementadorFactory () {
        }

        public static IMiImplementacion dameImplementacion(String nombreImplentacion) {
            if ("nombreImplentacion".equals(nombreImplentacion)) {
                return new MiImplementacion1();
            }
            if ("nombreImplentacion2".equals(nombreImplentacion)) {
                return new MiImplementacion2();
            }
            if ("nombreImplentacion3".equals(nombreImplentacion)) {
                return new MiImplementacion3();
            }  
            /*...Doscientas mil implementaciones más.....*/
    }
 }
```

¿Existe alguna otra forma mejor de utilizar este patrón? ¿Es posible que no haya elegido el patrón correcto para mi necesidad?

La utilidad que le quiero dar a esto es la de poder realizar unos formularios personalizados, los cuales, algunos de ellos son simples y siempre hacen lo mismo, obtener datos, guardar.. y otros que llevan otra serie de funciones específicas. estos últimos, son los que funcionarían con estas implementaciones particulares. 
El nombre de implementación se obtendría por ejemplo de una base de datos, cuando un dessarrollador quiere crear un nuevo formulario, podría poner su nombre y realizar su lógica particular.

Comment: ¿Realmente la elección de la  implementación solo depende de `nombreImplementación`? ¿O tienes luego otra lógica por separado para calcular `nombreImplementacion`?

Comment: Entiendo que esto es un ejemplo simplificado de tu código, pero como comenta @SJuan76 necesitaríamos más detalles para saber qué te aporta este patrón y la mejor forma de implementarlo. ¿Para qué usas las clases creadas?

Comment: He editado un poco la pregunta poniendo más información, si es necesario explayarse más puedo ser más conciso.

Comment: Si tienes que especificar el tipo de clase que quieres crear, `Factory` no es lo que necesitas.

Comment: @DavidDPG ¿Cuál sugieres que necesitaría para especificar el tipo de clase que quiero crear?

Answer (score 6):

Puesto que cualquier instancia debe poder crearse del mismo modo, asumo que todas las implementaciones de la interfaz tienen un constructor similar (en tu ejemplo sin parámetros).

Asumiendo esto, me imagino el uso que le das como lo siguiente:

```
IMiImplementacion f= ImplementadorFactory.dameImplementacion("Implementacion1");
```

Así que mi primera idea fue simplificar el método de tu factory a algo como lo siguiente:

```
public static IMiImplementacion dameImplementacion(String nombreImpl) {
   Class c= Class.forName(nombreImpl);
   return c.newInstance();
}
```

Pero entonces pienso que realmente no hay diferencia con hacer:

```
IMiImplementacion f= ImplementadorFactory.dameImplementacion(Implementacion1.class);
```

y tener el método:

```
public static IMiImplementacion dameImplementacion(Class implementacion) {
   return implementacion.newInstance();
}
```

Pero de nuevo, no veo que aporte nada que un clásico

```
 IMiImplementacion f= new Implementacion1();
```

no haga ya.

En general, el diseño *Factory* debería aportar algún tipo de valor añadido a la creación de objetos (la construcción es compleja, queremos tener singletons, queremos tener inyección de código...) pero en este caso simplemente crearía el objeto necesario en cada caso, directamente.

Suponiendo que la creación de los objetos es algo más compleja que la que expones, podrías sustituir los `if` por un más eficiente `switch`, que además suele ser más legible cuando el número de opciones crece:

```
public static IMiImplementacion dameImplementacion(String nombreImplentacion) {
    switch(nombreImplementacion) {
      case "nombreImplentacion1":
          return new MiImplementacion1();
      case "nombreImplentacion2":
          return new MiImplementacion2();
      case "nombreImplentacion3":
          return new MiImplementacion3();
      default:
          return null; //o lo que creas conveniente
    }
}
```

Comment: Tu primera idea me gusta, la segunda que simplificas no, ya que no es parametrizable.

Comment: Mi idea con esta respuesta es ayudarte a analizar lo que tienes y que decidas lo que te parece mejor, si ninguna de las dos ideas te convence tampoco sería malo si te ayudan a encontrar una mejor solución